# how to use a code in mac terminal

Tags: bash, matlab, shell, unix

I found a code that convert Matlab code to R

```
#!/bin/csh
cp $1 $2
ex -s $2 <<eof
   g/%/s//#/g
   g/function\(..*\)=\(..*\)(\(..*\)/s//\2 <-function( \3 { \1/
   g/end/s//   } #/
   g/for\(..*\)=\(..*\):\(..*\)/s//for ( \1 in \2 : \3 ) {/
   g/_/s//./g
   g/;/s///g
   g/==/s//@@/g
   g/=/s//<-/g
   g/@@/s//==/g
   g/zeros(/s//matrix(0,/g
   g/ones(/s//matrix(1,/g
   g/eye(/s//diag(1,/g
   g/\/s//solve(,)/g
   g/fsolve('\(..*\)'/s//ms(~\1 /g
   g/param(\(..*\))/s//param[ \1 ] /g
   g/var(\(..*\))/s//var[ \1 ] /g
   g/mod1(\(..*\)/s//mod1[ \1 /g
   wq
elf
```

I am a **Mac user** and I know that I should use this in terminal 
However, I don't know how to use it

Lets say I have a Matlab code here 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46966-preprocess-m/content//PreProcess.m

How can I use the above code in terminal to translate the Matlab code I mentioned in R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what what the script is doing you should use it like this :

```
./script.csh PreProcess.m NameOfRFile.r
```

In order to do that however, your script must executable. You can set the permissions like that :

```
chmod 700 script.csh
```

Of course csh should also be installed on your system. It probably already is by default, but otherwise, just install it with your packet manager.

Comment: Just for clarity, this answer assumes you have saved your script as `script.csh`. You then need to run the given `chmod` command **once**, **first**. Then you can use the `./script.csh ...` command as often as you like.